# Django - Como o decorator @login_required funciona nas views de uma outra app?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Eu tenho um projeto no Django e apenas uma aplicação onde realizo cadastros, pesquisas, login no sistema, etc. Estava lendo um artigo sobre a criação de projetos e vi que por questão de organização é normal ter varias aplicações no mesmo projeto, por ex: uma app para os cadastros, outra app para autenticar e logar o usuário no sistema, etc.

Minha duvida é a seguinte: Eu estou usando o decorator @login_required nas minhas views para que o usuario so tenha acesso as funcionalidades da aplicação se estiver logado. Se eu separar essa aplicação em varias, (uma para logar no sistema, outra para realizar os cadastros) eu posso continuar usando o decorator normalmente nas views das outras apps ?

*Obs: Django 1.6.2 e python 2.7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar sim!

O Django tem um [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) que é responsável pelo login de usuários "a nível de projeto", não estando atrelado a nenhum app que você criou.

Supondo que você já tenha um app usando o `@login_required` e que esteja funcionando normalmente, é só adicionar o decorator no outro app da mesma forma.